# How to read data from file while running the docker image

Tags: docker, dockerhub

i got a docker image which has a start.sh. the application starts with a configuration file. where do i put the configurtion file so that start.sh can read it?

```
sudo docker run -i -t   -p 9000:9000 localhost:5000/catalog-services_new /src/start.sh package.json
```

Suppose i want to read content of my package.json how can i do that.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want package.json inside your container or on your host ?

Comment: Package.json will be on my host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mount your package.json as a data volume:

http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-file-as-a-data-volume

```
docker run -it -v $(pwd)/package.json:/tmp/package.json debian:jessie bash
root@fa87321595c0:/# cat /tmp/package.json 
{

}
```

Comment: I now have similar approach, but instead of loading package.json file i will store file of host dir and mount that path and read from there. Mouting file does not look for me from design point.

Comment: As long as you have one file to mount I guess it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it anywhere:

```
COPY package.json /usr/local/etc/package.json
COPY start.sh /usr/local/bin/start.sh
```

In start.sh:

```
cat /usr/local/etc/package.json
```

Comment: Suppose i have file that doenot come with image ,say an connection_config file whcih is provided  by end client in that case what can we do?